# Render css class in image tag in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I am making an app in React, I hope to rotate and translate the image once clicked the button.

```js
render: function() {
    var imageSrc = this.props.imageSrc;
    var rotate = this.props.rotate;
    var translate = this.props.translate;
    var opacity = this.props.opacity;
    var scale = this.props.scale;
 
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={imageSrc} tyle={{opacity: opacity? 0.5:1,height: scale? 600:300, width: scale? 800:400}}/>
        <div>
          <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChangeFile} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I set the opacity and scale property in style tag, but I don't know how to add rotate and translate, since there is not html tag for them.

So i made a variable outside of JXS, 
      var imageRotate;
        if({rotate}===true){
          className='rotator'}

```
  return (
    <div>
     <img src={imageSrc} style={{className={imageRotate}/>
    <div>
```

but it doesn't work. i was wondering what is the best way to pass css into the image tag?

Answer (score 1):

In a react way, I would advise to separate concerns:

- make your before and after styling in css (and not use inline styles in react), and put the transform, rotate etc in the after-class.
- in your react code, add a click handler to your `<img>`, which applies the new class to your `<img>` component

Example code (where you change class every single time you click) would look something like this:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={ className: 'class1' }
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      className: (this.state.className=='class1')? 'class2' : 'class1'
    })
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <p className={this.state.className} 
         onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
           click me to change color
      </p>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

In this example, `class1` or `class2` is applied to a `<p>` element, but the principle is the same.

[Working codepen here](https://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/MyLLZo?editors=0010).

Answer (score 0):

Translating and rotating are part of the CSS `transform` property. You can set `transform` in the style pretty much like any other CSS.

For example, to work off the base React JSfiddle:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div style={{transform:"translate(10px, 10px) rotate(-15deg)"}}>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a02jkshm/